# How to find folders that do not exists using bash?

Tags: bash, filesystems

How to find using bash folders which dosen't exist in second level of the specified directory?

I have structure like:

```
- a
-- aa
--- aaa
---- myfolder <- if this folder dosen't exist I need to know that
-- ab
--- abc
---- myfolder <- if this folder dosen't exist I need to know that
```

I need to find in every "a" second level subfolder, folders "myfolder" that dosen't exist. Can you help?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script

Comment: I did regular while loop

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something with find and test e.g.

```
find /path/to/search -type d \! -exec test -e '{}/myfolder' \; -print
```

or

```
find  /path/to/search -maxdepth 1 -type d  \! -exec test -d '{}/myfolder' \; -print
```

<sup>it's late, the wine has been nice, your use case isn't clear - hic</sup>